# Postgrey logging options

Tags: postfix, syslog-ng, debian-bookworm, postgrey

I am running Debian 12, Postfix with Postgrey. I can not seem to get Postgrey to log to mail.log. I am using syslog-ng, was using rsyslog. I have mail pointing to the mail.log file and inside /etc/default/postgrey, I tried:

`POSTGREY_OPTS="--inet=127.0.0.1:10023 --greylist-action=ACTION --syslog-facility mail"`

also tried `--syslog-facility=mail` but nothing seems to force it to /var/log/mail.log I am trying to get it to mail.log so Monitorix will graph it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you get the messages still in syslog? if yes rsyslog can redirect the messages

Comment: Yes, they are in syslog. I pasted a link to my syslog-ng conf file below.

Answer (score 0):

Once you added this to your postfix main.cf it should log automatically. Depending on your logging settings in postfix.

smtpd_recipient_restrictions to

`check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023`

And your /etc/default/postgrey should like this

```
POSTGREY_OPTS="--inet=127.0.0.1:10023 --delay=60"
```

https://faq.ip-projects.de/en-us/10-server/40-postgrey-postfix-spam-filter-on-debian-ubuntu

Edit:Update

I have done a grep through your pastebin and this is what the config for mail is

```
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/mail.log"); };
# This files are the log come from the mail subsystem.
destination d_mailinfo { file("/var/log/mail.info"); };
destination d_mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail.warn"); };
destination d_mailerr { file("/var/log/mail.err"); };
filter f_debug { level(debug) and not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail); };
                    not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news); };
filter f_mail { facility(mail) and not filter(f_dbg); };
filter f_syslog3 { not facility(auth, authpriv, mail) and not filter(f_dbg); };
filter f_cother { level(debug, info, notice, warn) or facility(daemon, mail); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_info); destination(d_mailinfo); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_warn); destination(d_mailwarn); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_err); destination(d_mailerr); };
```

---

- Modify the postgrey configuration (usually located at
  `/etc/postgrey/postgrey.conf`)and put in

`LOGFILE="/var/log/postgrey.log"`  And restart the postgrey service

Also check to which syslog facility postgrey is logging.

- In `/etc/rsyslog.d/postgrey.conf` Make sure this is there
  `if $programname == 'postgrey' then /var/log/mail.log`
  And restart rsyslog

Comment: I have all that and it still logs postgrey to /var/log/syslog. unless I am missing something in your reply. Here is a copy of my mian.cf. Maybe you can see something wrong here. https://pastebin.com/QyVHEY2f

Comment: Why do you have `check_policy_service` twice in there?

Comment: Can you please install rsyslog back, then it's much easier https://serverfault.com/a/1020018/145902

Comment: One check_policy_service is postgrey, the other is SPF. I will reinstall rsyslog. Let me know what I need to change.

Comment: rsyslog is back. I created /etc/rsyslog.d/postgrey and used

if $programname == 'postgrey' then {
    /var/log/mail.log
      ~
}

But I an not seeing anything in mail.log nor syslog since installing rsyslog. 

Sample log: Feb  6 13:49:53 mail postgrey[1840745]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=o4.sendgridptr.vmware.com, 

Do I need a wildcard or something? postgrey[*] ?

Comment: I have one aspect of postgrey logging to mail.log now but it is only the message `Feb 07 17:00:32 mail postfix/smtpd[3888852]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from morningbrew-c.sailthru.com[192.64.236.184]: 450 4.2.0 <killswitch@demonweb.net>: Recipient address rejected: Greylisted, Temporary rejection, please try again later. This is a greylisting measure to protect yadda yadda`

I would like this log which is in daemon.log there

`Feb  6 13:49:53 mail postgrey[1840745]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=o4`

Comment: I will update my answer with what to do.

Comment: postgrey.conf did not exist so  I created it and restarted. Sent test email, no postgrey.log created. No changes. Question: Does the rsyslog.d/postgrey.conf entry require curly braces?

Comment: Got it working. The fix was stopping rsyslog and recreating the .service file for it. Then I started to see the logs for postgrey in mail.log but date format was new style. I put the $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat above
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf. rsyslog.service was bugging out